# Hide element when woocommerce cart is empty, appear on AJAX add to cart

Tags: php, ajax, function, woocommerce, cart

I have a woocommerce store where the number of items in the cart are shown next to the shopping cart icon in the header. The CSS selector for this area is **.woofc-menu-item-inner:after**. I'm currently using the code below to hide that element when the cart is empty:

```
    // Remove Item Count when Bag is Empty //

add_action('wp_head', 'hook_css', 99999);
function hook_css() {
    // If cart is empty hide the item count
    if(WC()->cart->is_empty())
        echo '<style type="text/css"> .woofc-menu-item-inner:after{display:none !important;}</style>';
}
```

But, the code above only works on page load. I currently use a couple of plugins (**Ajax add to cart for WooCommerce**, **Ajax Cart AutoUpdate for WooCommerce**) to update the cart's contents without reloading the page. Is there anyway to show/hide this element when an item is added/removed with AJAX?